# How do I add a counter that tells how many items of each are added in a cart in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The Main class

I want to add a counter that counts how many items have been added to the cart for a single item. My current code takes the total number of items in the basket and outputs it on the list tile of every item in the cart, of which is not what I want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'cart.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'The Wing Republic'),
    );
  }
}
```

The HomePage class

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Dish> _dishes = List<Dish>();

  List<Dish> _cartList = List<Dish>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateDishes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, top: 8.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_basket,
                    size: 35.0,
                  ),
                  if (_cartList.length > 0)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 8.0,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        child: Text(
                          _cartList.length.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                if (_cartList.isNotEmpty)
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Cart(_cartList),
                    ),
                  );

                setState(() {
                  if (_cartList.isEmpty) {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty, Add items to Cart",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildGridView(),
    );
  }
```

BuildListView Class

```
ListView _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _dishes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var item = _dishes[index];
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 8.0,
            vertical: 2.0,
          ),
          child: Card(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Text(item.category),
              /*Icon(
                item.icon,
                color: item.color,
              ),*/
              title: Text(item.brandName),
              subtitle: Text(item.price.toString()),
              trailing: GestureDetector(
                child: (!_cartList.contains(item))
                    ? Icon(
                        Icons.add_circle,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      )
                    : Icon(
                        Icons.remove_circle,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (!_cartList.contains(item))
                      _cartList.add(item);
                    else
                      _cartList.remove(item);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

GridView class

```
GridView _buildGridView() {
    return GridView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemCount: _dishes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _dishes[index];
          return Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.loose,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      /*Icon(
                        item.icon,
                        color: (_cartList.contains(item))
                            ? Colors.grey
                            : item.color,
                        size: 100.0,
                      ),*/
                      Text(item.category),
                      Text(
                        item.brandName,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "R" + item.price.toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 8.0,
                      bottom: 8.0,
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: (!_cartList.contains(item))
                            ? Icon(
                                Icons.add_circle,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              )
                            : Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (!_cartList.contains(item))
                              _cartList.add(item);
                            else
                              _cartList.remove(item);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
        });
  }
```

PopulateDishes class for my list

```
void _populateDishes() {
    var list = <Dish>[
      Dish(
        category: 'Gin Cocktails',
        brandName: "Clover Club",
        price: 65,
      ),
      Dish(
        category: 'WHISK(e)Y COCKTAILS',
        brandName: 'Select Reserve',
        price: 40,
      ),
      Dish(
        category: 'COGNAC/BRANDY COCKTAILS',
        brandName: 'Side Car',
        price: 110,
      ),
      Dish(
        category: 'RUM COCKTAILS',
        brandName: 'Mojito',
        price: 60,
      ),
      Dish(
        category: 'TEQUILLA COCKTAILS',
        brandName: "Margarita",
        price: 65,
      ),
      Dish(
        category: 'VODKA COCKTAILS',
        brandName: 'Cosmopolitan',
        price: 80,
      ),
      Dish(
        category: 'MOCKTAILS',
        brandName: 'Pina Colada ',
        price: 45,
      )
    ];

    setState(() {
      _dishes = list;
    });
  }
}
```

cart class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 8.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    item.category +
                    "\n" +
                    "R" +
                    item.price.toString()),
                title: Text(_cart.length.toString()),
                subtitle:GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {

                    setState(() {

                      _cart.add(item);
                    });
                  },
                )
                ,
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.remove_circle,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _cart.remove(item);
                      });
                    }),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey if ur code worked, write the answer here

Answer (score 0):

Currently, as per your program, you can have only single item of any dish in your cart. If you want multiple quantities of same item,  you will have to change this logic as well:

```
if (!_cartList.contains(item))
  _cartList.add(item);
else 
  _cartList.remove(item);
```

And maintain a map like map<Dish, quantity>. On click of add button, check if dish already exists in the map. If exists, add quantity, Else put that dish into map with initial quantity as 1. And similar logic for remove from cart.
Finally to display total cart items, loop over this map and go on adding the quantities of each dish.

Comment: I am lost as per your answer

Comment: What's your confusion?

Comment: Where do i put map<Dish, quantity>

Comment: Rather than List<Dish> _cart, have map<Dish,int>

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CartItem class which holds the dish and a counter, instead of adding the dish directly to the cart, you create a new CartItem and pass the dish as an argument, then inside the cart, you check if the item already exists, if so you increase the counter.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: hello but how to update the counter